# O365 ADConnect passwords not synchronizing

Tags: office365

Connected an existing AD to an existing O365. Accounts are synchronizing with the exception of passwords. Ran the troubleshooting tool and got the below error. Not sure what it means and not having luck with Google.

I get the error "Password hash synchronization has failed. Target AAD connector space object has not yet been exported".

New accounts work and have passwords updates. Accounts that were existing in O365 prior to ADConnect do not. Proxy address set to the proper SMTP name. Site was a .local, added alias UPN verified by Microsoft. Correct OU is being synched. Looking for some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see an error in the MIISClient.exe?
You can find it in the following directory: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Azure AD Sync\UIShell”